# Is there a word for this: an object that imitates the design of an old object?

Tags: word-choice

Is skeuomorph the correct word for this situation: I am writing a program which, given a picture of an old internet browser (Mosaic for example), creates a basic yet fully functional internet browser, using the picture as a skin, by overlaying a few native GUI controls over the picture. My goal is to make this object (a modern browser) look old - because I'm a bit nostalgic sometimes.

[image: The ELU website in the 90's renderedin Webview]

Comment: Yes technically correct but few people would know what it meant without wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

In the technical sense that you describe, I believe skeuomorphism or skeuomorphic design is the correct terminology.  A couple other more industry-neutral words include facade or overlay - for example:

"an 80's ***retro-facade***"

"a Mosaic ***overlay***"

An example of skeuomorphic design would be this Apple bookcase resembling an actual 3-D wooden bookcase:

[image: ibooks library depicted using skeuomorphic design to look like a real wooden bookcase]

Answer (score 2):

In architecture and other arts, this is called a *pastiche*.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what your audience is. The general public would probably prefer something easier on the ear. Perhaps something based on "retro" or "old-school". In search of your branding I suggest concentrating on what it provides, instead of thinking about semantics.

Comment: It's for an article about metaprogramming. I think the audience consists of programmers.

Comment: Samsung Galaxy 7?

Comment: @Antoine -- then Kristina answer, *skeuomorphism*, is defintely the right one.