# Word for vintage entity with modern technology

Tags: single-word-requests, technology

What word describes retro sounds/images incorporated into our modern technology?
For example, the sound of a phone ringing with an incoming call, or the click of a shutter when we take a photo with our iPhone?

Comment: The current article refers to these features as “nostalgic sounds:” https://interestingengineering.com/9-nostalgic-technology-sounds-that-will-make-you-feel-really-old

Comment: Thank you for your interest and response,Laurel,but I’m looking for a single word that defines these anachronistic entities.I just can’t remember it.

Comment: Compare this question: [Is there a word for this: an object that imitates the design of an old object?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91734/is-there-a-word-for-this-an-object-that-imitates-the-design-of-an-old-object)

Comment: Thanks so much,Stuart. It’s skeuomorph/skeuomorphic.

Comment: "throwback" is a word that comes to my mind

Comment: Note that a "skeuomorph" need not concern anything "modern" or "retro". If "skeuomorph" is what you want, then I recommend you edit the question; otherwise people may be confused, attempt to add irrelevant answers, etc.

Comment: What would be wrong with 'anachronistic' itself? In any case my view is that word, phrase or expression requests should be promoted to their own specialised community, perhaps named 'Vocabulary.'

Answer (score -1):

I might use "vestigiality" if you're going for one word. Otherwise "technological vestigiality". The one word requests are so tough sometimes! But fun. Hope you find the word you're looking for, as I am curious as well.

Answer (score -1):

I believe they would both be considered (nostalgic) "**memes**". Both of your examples are "audible", but that does not make them any different from more familiar "visual" **memes**.

[TFD - meme](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/meme)